# cc.net project visibility

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Is it possible to restrict the visibility of the projects listed in the cc.net Dashboard?

I have Projects 1, 2 and 3 listed in the Dashboard. I would like to move Projects 2 and 3 to a different dashboard. This is so I can hand out URL1 to dashboard1 that lists Porject1 and URL2 to Dashboard (listing Projects 2 and 3) to another set of people. Because the dashboard reads from the same cc.net.config file, is it possible to separate the projects, by, say adding an attribute?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if you look into the categories feature, it should help with what you are trying to do.

Both sets of users could navigate to the other category, but you would be able to meet your requirement of having separate distinct URLs for each category.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the category tags in order to sort them, you will get a link on the left to goto each group independently.  Just associate the group with each project you want in it and they will be under the link's page.

And if you're really ambitious you can make their own queues so each one can integrate independetly so they don't have to wait on some other category they don't care about.

```
<project name="CC.NET test" queue="testing" queuePriority="5">
  <category>Testing Group</category>
    ...
    ...
    ...
</project>
```