# Hierarchy Projects by using multiple CruiseControl.Net instances

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

We have many  projects that make up a system, the system has  ~2 major releases per year  which we have to support and back port some functionality

CruiseControl.NET is becoming unwieldy with each major release have  a new set of projects.

Is there a way

1. Create an CruiseControl.Net per major release, we have tried it out having a separate CC instances on separate ports but getting issues with Web page. Projects not showing up, so can't can't view the detail
2. CCTray works OK and suits developers, as they can control the projects listed
3. The Web page though  without a Hiearchy is tedious to use, is there a way to use servers, i.e.  add a server per release to web page with a name

Answer (score 0):

per 1. This should work. I had a similar setup, although with different CruiseControl.NET instances on separate machines - please make sure that the server's working / artifact directories are not overlapping.

per 3. Each project can have a [Category](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Project_Configuration_Block) configured, which is convenient for grouping. Both categories and separate servers, when added to a common web dashboard, can be viewed all at once or with a 'filtered' view. Also, the filtered view has a separate URL, so the users can go straight to the category they are interested in.

Related question: [cc.net project visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522555/cc-net-project-visibility)

Comment: I am struggling to find out all all about the features and how to set them up , I wil ltake a look at categories.